# Work Mac and home PC with same Apple ID causing problems

Tags: macos, icloud, apple-id

I used my personal Apple ID on a new work computer and now am having issues.  Bookmarked Favorites set on the work Mac appear on my home PC and vice versa.  iCloud photos available on the work Mac aren't accessible at home.  Personal Messages received on my iPhone pop up on my work computer.  How can I change the work Mac's Apple ID to stop this intermarrying?

Answer (score 3):

1. open iCloud preferences on the work Mac and sign out of iCloud
2. answer each question to delete all copies of that data locally
3. disco

Comment: Thanks, bmike.  I've signed out on the Mac.  Will see if it helps.